# Linux CLI tool or script library to query media files properties?

Tags: linux, command-line, media

Does anyone know of a tool that would allow me to get the properties of any media file, in a parseable way? Something similar to what ImageMagick's "identify" does for images:

```
$ identify libre.jpg 
libre.jpg JPEG 512x512 512x512+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 102KB 0.010u 0:00.009
```

A Perl, Ruby or Python library would do as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ffprobe` from [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) can do this:

```
ffprobe -show_format foo.avi
```

> FFmpeg is a complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and stream audio and video.

Comment: Thanks, that helps but unfortunately the geometry properties of the stream are not part of the standard, parseable output. I guess I can parse stderr to get those but I hoped there'd be a way to do that in a stricter way.

Comment: Ah, -show_streams does just that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `file`, but it's not really consistent:

```
$ file test.avi
test.avi: RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 800 x 600, 25.00 fps, video:
$ file test.mpg
test.mpg: MPEG sequence, v1, system multiplex
```

Via [Video file properties on the command line? - FedoraForum.org](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=182409) (also [command line - CLI: Extract metadata, properties from video files - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107236/cli-extract-metadata-properties-from-video-files)) - got [MediaInfo](http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download/Ubuntu), which has a more consistent output:

```
$ mediainfo test.avi
General
Complete name                            : test.avi
Format                                   : AVI
Format/Info                              : Audio Video Interleave
File size                                : 202 MiB
Duration                                 : 26s 480ms
Overall bit rate                         : 64.1 Mbps
Writing application                      : Lavf52.64.2

Video
ID                                       : 0
Format                                   : FFVH
Codec ID                                 : FFVH
Duration                                 : 26s 480ms
Bit rate                                 : 64.1 Mbps
Width                                    : 800 pixels
Height                                   : 600 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 5.338
Stream size                              : 202 MiB (100%)


$ mediainfo test.mpg
General
Complete name                            : test.mpg
Format                                   : MPEG-PS
File size                                : 2.22 MiB
Duration                                 : 26s 480ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 704 Kbps

Video
ID                                       : 224 (0xE0)
Format                                   : MPEG Video
Format version                           : Version 1
Format settings, BVOP                    : No
Format settings, Matrix                  : Default
Format settings, GOP                     : N=12
Duration                                 : 26s 480ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 690 Kbps
Width                                    : 800 pixels
Height                                   : 600 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.058
Stream size                              : 2.18 MiB (98%)
```

Finally, [Quickly Identify Video File Attributes | SavvyAdmin.com](http://savvyadmin.com/quickly-identify-video-file-attributes/) also mentions:

- [Idvid - Tovid Wiki](http://tovid.wikia.com/wiki/Idvid)
- [ExifTool by Phil Harvey](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)

Here's the output of `exiftool` for the same files as above:

```
$ exiftool test.avi 
ExifTool Version Number         : 8.15
File Name                       : test.avi
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 202 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2013:09:10 16:45:02+02:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : AVI
MIME Type                       : video/avi
Frame Rate                      : 25
Max Data Rate                   : 24.41 kB/s
Frame Count                     : 662
Stream Count                    : 1
Stream Type                     : Video
Video Codec                     : FFVH
Video Frame Rate                : 25
Video Frame Count               : 662
Quality                         : Default
Sample Size                     : Variable
Image Width                     : 800
Image Height                    : 600
Planes                          : 1
Bit Depth                       : 12
Compression                     : FFVH
Image Length                    : 1440000
Pixels Per Meter X              : 0
Pixels Per Meter Y              : 0
Num Colors                      : Use BitDepth
Num Important Colors            : All
Software                        : Lavf52.64.2
Duration                        : 26.48 s
Image Size                      : 800x600

$ exiftool test.mpg
ExifTool Version Number         : 8.15
File Name                       : test.mpg
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 2.2 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2013:09:12 14:02:36+02:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : MPEG
MIME Type                       : video/mpeg
Image Width                     : 800
Image Height                    : 600
Aspect Ratio                    : 1:1
Frame Rate                      : 25 fps
Video Bitrate                   : Variable
Image Size                      : 800x600
```